Statistical Model and its Topology
Consider the following setup:
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{B}, \mu)$ be a probability space and let us denote $\mathcal{M}_{\mu}$ the set of all densities of all probability measures equivalent to $\mu$:
$$
\mathcal{M}_{\mu} = \{ f \in L^1(\mu) : f > 0 \ \mu\text{-a.e. and} \ \mathbb{E}(f) = 1 \}.
$$
The probability measure whose density is $f$ will be denoted by $f \cdot \mu$ and its expectation by $\mathbb{E}_f(\cdot)$, where $\mathbb{E}(\cdot)$ denotes the expectation with respect to the reference measure $\mu$.
The paper that I am reading Paper is written that
"The more obvious geometry of $\mathcal{M}_{\mu}$ comes from the fact that it is a convex subset of $L^1(\mu)$. One of the key ideas in the geometric theory of statistical models is that embedding in $L^1(\mu)$ is not natural for statistical purposes."
$\textbf{My question is}$: Why is embedding $\mathcal{M}_{\mu}$ in $L^1(\mu)$ considered not natural for statistical purposes? What are the alternatives and the reasoning behind these alternatives in the context of the geometric theory of statistical models?

It'd probably be useful if you drop a reference to the paper in the question, just to give proper context. Also worth explicitly delineating the quote (maybe use a quote block, or at least " ") just so its clear what the paper says and what is you editorialising.

The paper attributes the claim to this book which I was unable to find online.

The alternative constructions are the ones discussed in the paper you link; Pistone, Sempi 95. We can consider instead various topologies on the ensemble of probability distributions. The typical case is the weak-topology but they discuss other ones with more differential-geometry theory behind them. For statistical practice, I'm not quite sure if I see detailed consequences from such abstract considerations? I'll read their paper and return to this question afterwards.

I find the sentence to be quite vague, but very high level, I suspect that the property they're talking about is the fact that the L_1 metric (which is the same as total variation) does not tensorise well, i.e., if $f^{\otimes n}$ is the distribution of $n$ iid samples from a density $f$, then it is difficult to relate $| f^{\otimes n} - g^{\otimes n}|_1$ to $|f-g|_1$ in a manner that effectively captures how the increase in $n$ makes distinguishing distributions (and thus doing statistics) easier.

Typical examples of such alternative structures are captured by expressing differences in distributions via an $f$-divergence (e.g., KL divergence is standard in information geometry), or via Hellinger-type metrics (which take $f \in L_1$ and map it to $f^{\alpha} \in L_{1/\alpha},$ and then study the problem in $L_{1/\alpha}$. Hellinger corresponds to $\alpha = 1/2$). The basic property that makes these useful is that the difference b/w $f^{\otimes n}, g^{\otimes n}$ becomes a simple function of the difference b/w $f,g$ and $n$ (e.g., $KL(f^{\otimes n}|g^{\otimes n}) = n KL(f|g))$.

I will try to give an intuitive picture of the situation.
Building on Fisher's work, Rao discovered that, on suitable manifolds of parametrized probability distributions like Normal distributions, the covariance matrix of a family of unbiased estimators is bounded from below by the inverse of a Riemannian metric tensor on the manifold of parameters determined by the fact that the points in the manifold parametrize probability distributions. This Riemannian metric tensor is known as the Fisher-Rao metric tensor (there is a lot to say regarding how to define this tensor rigorously, but I will not enter in this).
This link between statistics and geometry goes by the name of Cramér-Rao bound, and its history is quite interesting (I recall there is a paper discussing how this bound was discovered by Frechét before Cramér and Rao and other interesting things, but I forgot the title of this paper).
The Cramér-Rao bound makes the Fisher-Rao metric tensor important from the point of view of statistics, and the Fisher-Rao metric tensor "can not be derived from the $L^{1}$-geometry", as it can be verified considering a discrete and finite outcome space, and the manifold of all probability measures mutually absolutely continuous with respect to the counting measure.
Given this situation, a quite natural question is why and how the Fisher-Rao metric tensor appear. A beautiful answer to this question was given by Čencov in his monumental work.
Čencov's idea is that of looking for some kind of symmetry transformations of statistical models that are able to single out the Fisher-Rao metric tensor as the only Riemannian metric tensor invariant with respect to them.
For technical reasons, Čencov has to focus on discrete and finite outcome spaces, and to consider a more general class of symmetry transformations that are modelled in terms of morphisms in a suitable category.
The idea is that the symmetry transformations used in statistics may be related with coarse graining maps, for which we actually move to a statistical model on a bigger/smaller outcome space in such a way that relevant information is not lost (I know I am being quite un-rigorous, but a more precise formalization of this idea would require quite some work which I feel is outside the scope of the answer).
Once all the details are settled, the Fisher-Rao metric tensor emerges as the only possible Riemannian geometry which is invariant with respect to sufficient statistics, thus showing how statistical considerations lead to geometries that are not of the $L^{1}$-type.
Of course, Čencov's work can not be directly related to Pistone and Sempi's work, because the latter deals with outcome space that are not necessarily discrete and finite. Indeed, a fully satisfying extension of Čencov's result to generic outcome spaces is still missing, as far as I know (this work deals "only" with the case of smooth densities on closed manifolds of dimension greater than 1).
EDIT This book may be useful to understand better the technical details of statistical models on not-necessarily discrete and finite outcome spaces. The authors also comment on Pistone and Sempi's work and its technicalities, as well as on the rigorous definition of the Fisher-Rao metric tensor for very general models. However, the categorical framework envisaged by Čencov is abandoned in favor of a more measure-theoretic/functional-analytic one.

This sounds a lot like Jaynes' "Principle of Transformation Groups," I think?

I am not familiar with this principle. From what I understood by quickly looking at the wikipedia page, I would say they are only "distantly-related". Jaynes' principle seems connected with the choice of prior probabilities, while Čencov's idea is concerned with the possible Riemannian geometries on probabilities. However, it is true that symmetry transformations are kind of a"universal trope" in mathematics.

Great summary. Thank you very much.

@GuillaumeDehaene: thank you very much. I really like this subject, especially when its quantum counterpart enters the game to make things even more interesting. At some point, I would really like to have the time to sit down and write a (presumably quite long) review of all this.

A tangential answer, but I want to share a great paper on this topic: What is a statistical model?
, McCullaugh 2002
The author provides a detailed characterization of statistical models in terms of category theory. It's a tough read, but it does highlight (in very unnatural and heavy, but accurate(!), language) some key properties that a statistical model should have. In particular, the author discusses how the intuitive properties: "my model should give predictions" "the predictions should be sensible" "the model should aim to be universal" can be encoded into category-theory language over models.

This is fantastic!  This might become one of my go-to references for when people have trouble interpreting model-relative probabilities that can't actually be interpreted because the framing renders them meaningless.  One of the first questions anyone has when thinking about statistics seriously is "where does the hyperparameter tree hit bottom?"  - I think this is the first paper I've read that provides a reasonable framing for an answer.

@user3716267 It's a great paper. But. While I don't think I have quite understood this paper at a deep enough level, I'm a bit worried that it's a too limiting. I'm very appreciative and impressed at how they turn the "artisanal" aspects of statistics into something more rigorous. For the time being, I would still stick to my artisanal knowledge, though.
